# add xctest framework to an old project

Tags: ios, iphone, xctest

how can I add xctest framework to an old project? When I try to add a new framework I couldn't find xctest in the available list in Link Binaries With Libraries.

I also tried edit->refractor->convertToXCTEst but select targets to use xctest: lists no targets

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Xcode 6.1.1, and also in Xcode 6.0.1, the XCTest.framework is not listed anymore as an available framework. In Xcode 5.1.1, however, the framework is listed.

So something appears to have changed between Xcode 5 and 6 when it comes to testing. For instance, when you create a new project in Xcode 6 you no longer need the XCTest framework. You can simply add a new test case, build and the test runs just fine. I have yet to figure out why this is the case, but for you this might be the first thing to try: Just code a test case and see whether things work.

If they don't, then you could try this ugly workaround: Open the project with an older version of Xcode, add the framework there, then go back to work in your new version of Xcode. This worked for me when I tried it with Xcode 5.1.1.

---

EDIT: The reason why XCTest.framework is no longer needed in projects created by Xcode 6 is because these projects have the build setting CLANG_ENABLE_MODULES set to YES. Xcode 6 exposes this in the UI under the name "Enable Modules (C and Objective-C)". With this setting enabled, any `#import` statements for system frameworks such as XCTest cause `clang` to automatically link against that framework. Details are available in the ["Modules" section of the clang documentation](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/Modules.html). Once this build setting is enabled you can also remove any other system frameworks from the "Link Binary with Libraries" build phase of your targets.

And for completeness' sake: The reason why Xcode 6 no longer lists XCTest.framework as an available framework is because the framework's location inside the Xcode bundle has changed:

```
# Xcode 6
/Applications/Xcode-6.1.1.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/Library/Frameworks/XCTest.framework
# Xcode 5
/Applications/Xcode-5.1.1.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS7.1.sdk/Developer/Library/Frameworks/XCTest.framework
```

Apparently Apple now relies entirely on CLANG_ENABLE_MODULES to get test targets to link against XCTest.framework. If you want Xcode 6 to list XCTest.framework as an available framework, you can manually create a symbolic link inside the Xcode app bundle:

```
cd /Applications/Xcode-6.1.1.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks
sudo ln -s /Applications/Xcode-6.1.1.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/Library/Frameworks/XCTest.framework .
```

You need to restart Xcode after creating the link.